# How do I install a driver provided as source code?

Tags: installation, drivers, hardware, compiling

I have a USB-to-LAN converter, and downloaded the its drivers. The driver folder consists of a `Makefile` file, a `.c` file and a `.h` file.

How do I install such a driver?

Answer (score 1):

- Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Install the *build-essential* package with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install build-essential
  ```
- Change the directory to the extracted driver folder; suppose it's under your home directory as `Downloads/driversource`, with:

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads/driversource
  ```
- Type `make && sudo make install`

This should build and install the driver. You will probably need to reboot to activate the installed driver.

Comment: I want to compile this https://github.com/Stane1983/kernel-amlogic-mx/tree/master/drivers/amlogic/dvb/si2168 , but it says "make: *** No targets.  Stop."