# installing drivers for intel 910 series SSD (data center hdd), how it it possible?

Tags: drivers, ssd

I got my hands on a Intel 910 series 800GB SSD, now I have a hard time installing it since Ubuntu is not mentioned as a supported OS for it. And I might add that I am a newbie with Linux as well so this is a shot in the dark.

The special thing with this SSD is that it requires drivers to be used and it will therefore not show up in BIOS or be bootable etc.

I found this blog-post about some guy using the SSD in Ubuntu during benchmarking:
http://www.percona.com/blog/2012/09/11/intel-ssd-910-vs-hdd-raid-in-tpcc-mysql-benchmark/

So it should be possible to use it in Ubuntu, the question is how.

In the readme for the linux-drivers (for redhat and suse) it mentions three ways of installing:

1. Installing from a Floppy disk
2. Installing from RPM
3. Installing from source

The first alternative involves creating a bootable floppy. When i look into the ISO file used it seems to still be using RPM's which I guess is not used by ubuntu.

The second alternative is also non-ubuntu(I guess?)

The third might be possible though. The driver bundle contains a folder named mpt2sas which contains .c and .h -files together with a Makefile. I've tried compiling it according to [How do I install a driver provided as source code?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177329/how-do-i-install-a-driver-provided-as-source-code) but all I got was "target missing".

This is the complete readme file that was included:
http://marin-el.se/process/Intel_SSD%20910_Series_README_Linux.txt

It mentions moving the sourcefiles to certain location and after that I think the kernel needs to be rebuilt.

Is rebuilding the kernel the way to go? And would it be possible to follow the steps in the readme file for doing that or is it so difficult that it makes more sense to switch OS and use Suse instead(I'd rather not)?

//TB

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you wanting to install this to?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit but I would consider changing if it's needed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question appears to be abandoned

Answer (score -1):

You can try the .rpm package, its nothing but a different package type.

Theres a tool called Alien that adds .rpm support to debian variatives which Ubuntu is. The 910 works without special drivers in Ubuntu 14.04 you can partition, format and mount the 4 partitions as you like.

Comment: Using Alien and a package meant for another distribution is nothing but asking for trouble.