# I have a driver supplied as source cod (.c) cannot install 'build-essentials'

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, compiling

Found this question and answer "[How do I install a driver provided as source code?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177329/how-do-i-install-a-driver-provided-as-source-code)".
When I followed the instruction: "sudo apt-get install build-essentials"
got the response "E: Unable to locate package build-essentials".

I'm running as root in armbian 16.04 which has all upgrades (except to 18.) and updates compiled for a H2 CPU on an Orange PI Zer0+

What can I do now?
Peter.

Comment: I usually don't type the full package name, type part of it and hit <tab><tab> so auto-complete can complete or show me my choices & refresh my memory.

Comment: Possible off-topic question, armbian is not Ubuntu, nor an official flavour of Ubuntu, thus off-topic (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Thank you, I've put that on a sticky note so I'll remember it. Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's `build-essential`  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/build-essential)

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Comment: Thank you.  At least I didn't originate the misspelling (Oh. the embarrassment).