# module build resource not found trying to make a driver from .C source

Tags: drivers, compiling, make

Found this:  "[How do I install a driver provided as source code?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177329/how-do-i-install-a-driver-provided-as-source-code)."
After an answer here corrected some spelling, got as far as the 'make step'.

Here’s the Makefile:

```
obj-m := GobiSerial.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

all: clean
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions Module.* modules.order
```

Which produces the response:

```
rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions Module.* modules.order
make -C /lib/modules/3.4.113-sun8i/build M=/usr/src/SIM7600LinuxDriver/GobiSerial modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.4.113-sun8i/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems I need to install something, but what?

Comment: What for is this driver you’re trying to install, and on which machine and OS (flavour, version) are you trying to install it? Searching for the relevant parts of the missing directory’s path I found http://linux-sunxi.org/Sun8i_emac. Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

There is supposed to be a link 'build' in '/lib/modules/3.4.113-sun8i' which points at 
at   '/usr/src/linux-headers-sun8i'  I put that link in and the make worked.
I already had the headers installed.

Peter